# Puppet forge tomcat module - start as a systemd service

Tags: tomcat, puppet, systemd, forge, systemctl

I have got the puppet forge module puppetlabs-tomcat installing and configuring Tomcat 8, OK.

I have it configuring database connections, a custom realm and deploying a war file. It works and Puppet starts Tomcat if it is not already running.

I want to change things so that Puppet runs Tomcat as a systemd service.

Getting Puppet to create a systemd service file in /etc/systemd/system using an epp template was easy. Having done this systemd's systemctl commands for start, stop and status work perfectly.

The issue I'm stuck on is getting puppetlabs-tomcat's service definition to start Tomcat as a systemd service. It looks like it should be easy because tomcat::service has parameters to define the start and stop commands.

```
tomcat::service { 'myWebApp':
  catalina_home  => $catalinaHome,
  catalina_base  => $catalinaBase,
  start_command  => "systemctl start ${systemdServiceName}",
  stop_command   => "systemctl stop ${systemdServiceName}",
}
```

Sadly those two parameters are not having the desired effect.

The service I have defined in my systemd service file includes the phrase:

```
Environment=CATALINA_PID=<%= $catalinaBase %>/temp/tomcat.pid
```

This intentionally specifies a different .pid file to one I've seen created when Tomcat is started by default settings in puppetlabs-tomcat. This difference enables me to be sure I know how Tomcat was started.

What I want is for Puppet to start Tomcat via systemd and thus eliminate any discrepancy depending on whether Tomcat was started by Puppet or directly via systemd.

Comment: What do you mean exactly by "has no effect"? Does the class try to start the service another way, are any Tomcat processes active after the run, whether from Puppet or others? A `--debug` level log may be useful, it'll show which service status commands are being run.

Comment: Hello Dominic, Puppet was starting Tomcat by means other than systemd. I have a solution now. I asked pretty much the same question here: https://tickets.puppetlabs.com/browse/MODULES-4204 and Hunter Haugen came up with a solution.  It is nothing like I was expecting, it doesn't specify the start and stop commands but it invokes systemd start and stop perfectly.